# Access forwarded port in vagrant over network

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, portforwarding, vagrantfile

I have a vagrant VM with provider VirtualBox. I need to access a port on the VM from over the network. The VM should not be accessible throw the network.
I have setup a private network in my Vagrantfile and forwarded the port in question. Now I can reach the port from within the host. What I want is to access the port on the from other machines in the network. This does not work.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2" 
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.box = "trusty64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'

  config.vm.network "private_network", type:"dhcp"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4242, host: 4242
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000


  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.cpus = 4
  end


end
```

On the host opening the URL 127.0.0.1:4242 lets me access the service running there.

What I want is to access the service over the network using the host public IP.

Answer (score 1):

When we use Vagrant's port forwarding in a private network, we have the following bindings on the host:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5463/VBoxHeadless
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4242            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5463/VBoxHeadless
```

Ports are bounded to `0.0.0.0` i.e. we can access them on any host's IP address, not only `127.0.0.1`.

So, you can access the port on VM from any network host by network IP of the host where VM is, for example `192.168.0.106:4242`.

Before that please make sure that the firewall rules on host allows to access ports `3000` and `4242` from the outside network.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work. I am only able to reach the service  from the host itself. Trying to reach the service from other hosts of the same network, the service is not reachable. When starting the service on the host itself (e.g not using Vagrant), i am able to reach the service, so there is no firewall issue here. Any ideas, why i am not able to reach the service using the VM. I also tried with a public network, which neither works.

Comment: What OS do you use? It works fine on Ubuntu 16.04, for example.

Comment: The host is a CentOS 7 machine, while the VM is a Ubuntu 14.04.